# How to build reports in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to generate 10 business reports based on the following tables and I'm having some troubles. I know I do not have enough for 10 reports yet, but I am having troubles starting.

CARE_CENTER

```
Care Center ID|Care Center Name      |Care Center Address                        |Nurse In Charge
------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------
 11111      |Centers Health Care     |4770 White Plains Rd, Bronx, NY            |Nurse Johnson
 22222      |Bronx Urgent Care       |1733 E 174th Street, Bronx, NY             |Nurse Robinson
 33333      |BronxCare Special Care Center|1265 Fulton Avenue, Bronx, NY         |Nurse Jones
 44444      |Gold Crest Care Center  |2316 Bruner Avenue, Bronx, NY              |Nurse Gonzalez
 55555      |Regeis Care Center      |3200 Baychester Avenue, Bronx, NY          |Nurse Waterman
 66666      |MedCarePlus             |1643 Westchester Avenue, Bronx, NY         |Nurse Connor
 77777      |ArchCare Senior Center  |900 Intervale, Avenue, Bronx, NY           |Nurse Rodriguez
 88888      |Bronx Center for Rehab  |1010 Underhill Avenu, Bronx, NY            |Nurse Morales
```

VISIT_CARE_CENTER

```
Patient ID|Visit Number|Care Center ID 
-------------+-----------------+-----------------
 1122         |78945         |11111
 2233         |89123         |22222
 3344         |91456         |33333
 4455         |64981         |44444
 5566         |12065         |55555
 6677         |98106         |66666
 7788         |40169         |77777
 8899         |26013         |88888
```

Volunteer_Assigned_Care_Center

```
Volunteer ID|Care Center ID
----------------+------------------
 12333           |11111
 23444           |22222
 34555           |33333
 45666           |44444
 56777           |55555
 67888           |66666
 78999           |77777
 89000           |88888
```

VOLUNTEER

```
Volunteer ID|Interest ID
---------------+-------------
 12333          |00001
 23444          |00002
 34555          |00003
 45666          |00004
 56777          |00005
 67888          |00006
 78999          |00007
 89000          |00008
```

INTEREST

```
Interest ID|Interest Description
--------------+--------------------
 00001        |Organzing
 00002        |Coordinating
 00003        |Daily Activites
 00004        |Assisting with fundraising
 00005        |Planning Special Events
 00006        |Feeding Patients
 00007        |Cleaning Social Rooms
 00008        |Caring for Visitors
```

I need to generate a report that shows the Care centers and the volunteer relationships.

How would I write the SQL query to generate this report based on the above table structure?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need a join first

```
    Select c.CareCenterID, 
     c.CareCenterName, 
     c.CareCenterAddress, 
     c.NurseInCharge, v.VolunteerID, 
    i.InterestID, i.InterestDescription

    From 
   CARE_CENTER c
   Join
   Volunteer_Assigned_Care_Center va
   On
   c.CareCenterID =va.CareCenterID
   Join
   VOLUNTEER v
   On va.VOLUNTEERId=
    v.VOLUNTEERId
    Join
    Interest i
     v.InterestId=i.InterestId
```

Comment: Not a report this is just a sql query which will give you your related data if you are using some reporting tool or oracle sql developer you can just export the results obtained by the above query into csv

Comment: Also if you want to manually prepare a report than after running the above query in your database you can refer the syntax in the below link which i have shared for reference https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_six.htm#SQPUG016

Comment: So I can use the above query THEN put the information in?